# jQuery toggle and animate not working

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

What is wrong with the following jQuery code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#contact_min").click(function(){
    $("#contact_min").toggle(function(){
      $("#contact_min").animate({
        height: "300px"
      }, 1500 );
    $(".arrow").html("&#x25bc;")}
    function(){
      $("#contact_min").animate({height: "28px"}, 1500 );
      $(".arrow").html("&#x25B2;")
    })});
</script>
```

It does nothing when I click on the contact_min div.

HTML:

```
<div id="contact_min">
  <span class="arrow">&#x25B2;</span>
  <span class="text">foobar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I suggest you to look at the [Jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/), everything is explained in there.

Comment: You are missing a comma(,) in the following position $(".arrow").html("&#x25bc;") } , function(){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do nothing. It binds up another event to handle clicks. When you click it again you will see something happen, but then it will bind up yet another event. After that every click will have multiple handlers that do opposite things, and every click will bind up even more handlers.

Just remove the `click` method call, the `toggle` method binds an event for the click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#contact_min").toggle(function(){
  $("#contact_min").animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, 1500 );
  $(".arrow").html("&#x25bc;")
},
function(){
  $("#contact_min").animate({
    height: "28px"
  }, 1500 );
  $(".arrow").html("&#x25B2;")
});
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing comma between the two functions, too?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it myself without the click already, but adding the comma did the trick :)

Comment: @Aioros: Yes, you are right, there should be a comma. I added it to the code.

Answer (score 1):

there is no .toggle animate i think you need to do something like:

```
$("#contact_min").click(function(){
  var height = $("#contact_min").attr("height");
  if height!=28px
  {
   $("#contact_min").animate({
    height: "28px"
    }, 1500 );
  $(".arrow").html("&#x25B2;");
  }
  else
  {
  $("#contact_min").animate({
    height: "300px"
    }, 1500);
  $(".arrow").html("&#x25bc;")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the click function because the toggle already has a interchanging click event.

So it will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#contact_min").toggle(function(){
 $("#contact_min").animate({
 height: "300px"
 }, 1500 );
 $(".arrow").html("&#x25bc;")
 }
 function(){
 $("#contact_min").animate({
 height: "28px"
 }, 1500 );
 $(".arrow").html("&#x25B2;")
 });
 </script>
```